# Ascending group by date

Tags: r, dplyr

I cannot able to ascend my group by dates. Please help!

```
df <- data.frame(A = c('a1','a1','b1','b1','b1','c2','d2','d2'),
                B = c("2017-02-20","2018-02-14","2017-02-06","2018-02-27","2017-02-29","2017-02-28","2017-02-09","2017-02-10"))
```

Code:

```
df %>% group_by(A) %>% arrange(A,(as.Date(B)))
```

I am getting wrong result as the `b1` didn't sort

```
       A          B
  <fctr>     <fctr>
1     a1 2017-02-20
2     a1 2018-02-14
3     b1 2017-02-06
4     b1 2018-02-27
5     b1 2017-02-29
6     c2 2017-02-28
7     d2 2017-02-09
8     d2 2017-02-10
```

Comment: Yes, that would be the case `as.Date(df$B)`

Comment: @DaveT I don't think it is a duplicate, I just checked your link. The issue is not with converting, but having incorrect data element.

Comment: Yes, after changing the invalid date it worked fine thanks!

Comment: @akrun, there were no comments when I started answering and setting up the `reprex` environment . I didn't mean to take credit apologies to d.b and you!

Comment: @x85ms16  that's fine.  Thank you for the reply

Answer (score 2):

You can see that the `2017-02-29` is not a real date, only 28 days in feb 2017. So, when you are converting your column B to date, it converts that value to NA. Fix that entry and it your answer should work.

Also, you probably do not need to `group_by A`

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 

df <- data.frame(A = c('a1','a1','b1','b1','b1','c2','d2','d2'),
                 B = c("2017-02-20","2018-02-14","2017-02-06","2018-02-27","2017-02-29","2017-02-28","2017-02-09","2017-02-10"))

as.Date(df$B)
#> [1] "2017-02-20" "2018-02-14" "2017-02-06" "2018-02-27" NA          
#> [6] "2017-02-28" "2017-02-09" "2017-02-10"

df%>%arrange(A, as.Date(B))
#>    A          B
#> 1 a1 2017-02-20
#> 2 a1 2018-02-14
#> 3 b1 2017-02-06
#> 4 b1 2018-02-27
#> 5 b1 2017-02-29
#> 6 c2 2017-02-28
#> 7 d2 2017-02-09
#> 8 d2 2017-02-10
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>